# Get rid of drop down cc-bcc-reply-to field when composing in Mail?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, apple-mail

Is there any way to get rid of the drop down cc bcc reply-to etc. field menu in the compose new message window in Mail in Mac OS X Snow Leopard?

The offending menu is the one immediately to the left of the Subject field when composing a new message, and it interrupts me as I try to tab from To: to Subject: to the message body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've discovered that using enter instead of tab, I can switch from to: to cc: to bcc: to subject: to the message body without landing on the annoying box. So that doesn't technically explain how to get rid of the box, but it does solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the View menu. There you have 'CC Address Field' and 'BCC Address Field' which allow to specify if the fields should be shown or not.

Comment: I don't think he's talking about the B/CC address fields, but the dropdown menu between the subject field and message body, the menu for setting the visibility of the B/CC fields.

Comment: Correct--I meant the annoying little arrow box. However, see my answer....

Answer (score 1):

You want to remove the pop up menu in the compose new mail window?  While in theory this could be done, if you remove the pop up from the NIB of the Apple Mail...

I don't think that there is any official way to do this, and not one that would easily carry on with any software updates from Apple...